# how do i get the filename of my upload?

Tags: php, variables, upload

this is part of an image upload script i made. I decided to name the rename the images i upload to the time i upload.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$mvTime = date("dmy").(date("H")+5).date("is");
$folder = "images/";
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w, $orig_h);

imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.$mvTime.'.jpg', 100);
```

now when i upload the image, it saves the image like 051112174700.jpg . its the date in dmyHis format. now i am confused how i show a preview of the image. because the time is changing all the time. thats why i cant use $folder.$mvTime.'jpg' in the  tag src.

can any body help me how i can get the image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use session for temporally  save image names

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$mvTime = date("dmy").(date("H")+5).date("is");
$folder = "images/";
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w, $orig_h);

imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.$mvTime.'.jpg', 100);

$_SESSION['img_temp_name']=$mvTime.'.jpg';
```

Comment: & how exactly  is that possible ?

Comment: yeah. thank you.. but it seems you can do the same thing with a variable too :D thankx

Comment: tested like this

$varvar = "asdf". $mvTime;
echo $varvar."<br/>";
sleep(10);
echo $varvar;

Answer (score 2):

You know the path of the image already - `$folder.$mvTime.'jpg'`.

It is not clear from your question but if you want to show a preview immediately after uploading then inside PHP you could do the following:

```
echo '<img src="'.$folder.$mvTime.'jpg" />";
```

Alternatively, you will need to come up with a naming convention that allows you to find the image you want later, or store information on the images somewhere (such as in a database).

Comment: If it in same page it is ok, Good answer if he used Database problem solved easily

Answer (score 2):

You defined the image location in the `mvTime`, so use it like this?

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$mvTime = date("dmy").(date("H")+5).date("is");
$folder = "images/";
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w, $orig_h);

imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.$mvTime.'.jpg', 100);

echo '<img src="'.$folder.$mvTime.'.jpg" />'; // <---- added this
```